# How to improve load time when Pingdom says 80% of the load time is the web browser waiting for data from the server?

Tags: performance

tools.pingdom.com gives a speed analysis of any given website. What does it mean when most of the load time is spent on waiting? I am using a CDN.

[image]

Comment: The percentage is not he metric to look at. What are the actual load times?

Comment: Load time 6.56s

Comment: Is that the total including DNS? Even then, that is quite a bit slow. BTW- not all CDNs are fast. Can I ask what CDN? I do not know a good one from a bad one, but someone here might have experience with CDNs and can comment or answer.

Comment: I'm using CloudFlare

Comment: Wow. That is one of the big ones. CloudFlare is not without fault however. It has problems with hosting low quality domains that can drop a site from the SERPs because of being associated with a bad neighborhood. I just do not deal with these things enough to know about performance. Someone will. I would have expect more from them.

Comment: For what it is worth, I up-voted this hopefully this will get you some attention. It seems rather quiet here tonight.

Comment: Can you provide more data? If you use chrome, go to the page, right click, select inspect element, select the timeline tab, reload the page, and then post a screenshot.

Comment: @User We really would need more information about your site in order to answer this specifically, otherwise users will just be guessing. Please edit this as Daniel F suggested to at least include a [waterfall](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76995/how-do-i-determine-if-a-redirection-was-due-to-dns-or-the-webserver/76996#76996) screenshot so that we have a better idea of what the factors might be. You may also want to do comparison testing with CloudFlare's caching under _Performance Settings_, while being aware that it takes time for caching to occur on servers around the world.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna assume that the website you tested is dynamic. It's probably made in PHP, ASP, or some other scripting language that produces output based on the operation of running code (other than HTML) and the input passed into it (including user's ip, etc).

When the script as well as server resources are poorly used, long wait times result.

For example, Say the website has a gigantic database in the background with 1 billion or so records. Seeing that I work with databases myself, trying to get a count on a huge amount of records even on a fast system takes time in milliseconds, and these milliseconds add up, and if the script that produces the page you're trying to view ends up trying to get a count on the billion of records several times throughout the script without caching the results at all then the waiting time can be very large and I personally would fire the programmer of the company if I had the power.

Answer (score 2):

Basically "Waiting" can have lot of meaning and are given below :

1 - May be your server response time in high , I mean slow.

2 - Your coding has issues OR it has not standard way to retrieve resources.

3 - Images used in website are not optimized and having huge size in MB.

4 - May be you are calling more 3rd party scripts

5 - Your way to loading site resources may not be standard

So there can be anything as reason of waiting.

I recommend you to use : [Google page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) OR [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) to analyze your site and to get actual issue of slow loading.